# User points by week instead of running total

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm new to SQL so pardon any rookie mistakes...

Every week, a user will answer 10 questions and I will track their progress over time. For each user, I want to find the total score of correctly answer questions, displayed by week. So a result would look something like this:

> > userID = 1
> >
> > weekID = 3
> >
> > TotalPoints = 5

**Here are my columns:**

- userID, weekID,
- QuestionA, QuestionA_ID, A_Correct, PointsA
- QuestionB, QuestionB_ID, B_Correct, PointsB
- TotalPoints *(PointsA + PointsB)*

**Here's my query:**

```
SELECT userID, weekID, 
SUM(DISTINCT PointsA + PointsB) as TotalPoints
FROM Results [LIMIT 0,3],
    (SELECT SUM(DISTINCT PointsA)
    FROM Results
    WHERE A_Correct = "Y" and userID = "1"),

    (SELECT SUM(DISTINCT PointsB)
    FROM Results
    WHERE B_Correct = "Y" and userID = "1")
WHERE userID = "1" and weekID < "10"
GROUP BY weekID ORDER BY weekID ASC;
```

It appears as though I'm getting aggregate totals from all weeks instead of totals for each week. Any thoughts on where I'm going wrong? Ways to do this better? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
select userID, weekID,
       sum(case when A_Correct = 'Y' then PointsA else 0 end) as PointsA,
       sum(case when B_Correct = 'Y' then PointsB else 0 end) as PointsB,
       (sum(case when A_Correct = 'Y' then PointsA else 0 end) +
        sum(case when B_Correct = 'Y' then PointsB else 0 end)
       ) as TotalPoints
from results
where weekId < 10
group by userId, weekID;
```

I do not know what the `limit` is supposed to be doing in the query, nor the `DISTINCT`.  If you want to select just one user, then add a `where` clause before the `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT userID
, weekID
, SUM(case when A_Correct = 'Y' then pointsA else 0 end) 
+ SUM(case when B_Correct = 'Y' then pointsB else 0 end) 
as TotalPoints
FROM Results 
WHERE userID = 1
and weekID < 10
GROUP BY weekID 
ORDER BY weekID ASC;
```

Comment: This is awesome. I really appreciate your help! Your code was also cleaner than the previous answer which is a bonus. Unfortunately SO won't let me assign multiple answers as correct (bummer dude) I'll get my rep up and return the karma. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries, Gordon beat me to it by a minute, so rightfully deserves the points - thanks though, and good luck.